# Parts of mesh appear dark in 3d view and in render

Tags: rendering, mesh

I have an issue with a part of my model. It looks weird in object mode as well as in a render. Please look at the attached screencaps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I checked and all the geometry in and around this problem have all 4 verticies and 4 edges, making one face. this entire section was rebuilt after I forgot to extrude something. The odd thing is that just these two faces look weird but not the surrounding ones that I stitched together in the same manner.

I looked in ortho views and they are all aligned so it isn't that some verts may be offset.

Comment: In edit mode select your mesh and do Ctrl N

Comment: thanks that fixed it. Why?

Comment: Killerpixler: the normals for the dark faces were flipped. CTRL+N in Edit mode recalculates the normals so they're all going the same way. You can read more about them at the bottom of this page: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Faces